# Mobile App crashes after enabling R8 in release build

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

I am new to android development. I developed an android application which was working perfectly fine before enabling R8. After obfuscating the application, I am getting the following error. I have no idea where am I going wrong.

Following is the Logcat console:

```
2020-01-28 16:16:09.404 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2020-01-28 16:16:09.405 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j6ltecis/j6lte:9/PPR1.180610.011/J600FXXU5BSH5:user/release-keys'
2020-01-28 16:16:09.405 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '2'
2020-01-28 16:16:09.405 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2020-01-28 16:16:09.405 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG: pid: 5073, tid: 5073, name: e.peopleconnect  >>> pk.com.ke.peopleconnect <<<
2020-01-28 16:16:09.405 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2020-01-28 16:16:09.405 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'interpreter_common.h:269] Check failed: receiver->GetClass()->ShouldHaveEmbeddedVTable() '
2020-01-28 16:16:09.405 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     r0  00000000  r1  000013d1  r2  00000006  r3  00000008
2020-01-28 16:16:09.405 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     r4  000013d1  r5  000013d1  r6  fff98dac  r7  0000010c
2020-01-28 16:16:09.405 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     r8  0000000b  r9  efecd000  r10 d4dfe09c  r11 fff98ed0
2020-01-28 16:16:09.405 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     ip  00000041  sp  fff98d98  lr  f3233115  pc  f3229fce
2020-01-28 16:16:09.441 3242-3316/? D/SensorService: [SO] -1.307 4.961 9.835
2020-01-28 16:16:09.441 3242-3316/? D/SensorService: [SO] [0 -> 255]
2020-01-28 16:16:09.469 2818-26162/? V/APM_AudioPolicyManager: getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice
2020-01-28 16:16:09.470 2818-26162/? V/APM_AudioPolicyManager: getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0
2020-01-28 16:16:09.470 2818-26162/? V/APM_AudioPolicyManager: ### curdevice : 2
2020-01-28 16:16:09.592 3242-3384/? D/WifiTrafficPoller: TrafficStats TxPkts=394436 RxPkts=647369 TxBytes=46490190 RxBytes=822657331 , Foreground uid=10240 pkgName=pk.com.ke.peopleconnect TxPackets=84 RxPackets=73 TxBytes=12001 RxBytes=49973
2020-01-28 16:16:09.604 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2020-01-28 16:16:09.604 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0001cfce  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+58)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.604 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0035e2ff  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1034)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.604 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000071c3  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+506)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 003f68fd  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+548)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00417814  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 001f309c  /data/app/pk.com.ke.peopleconnect-3XBY7V7mKYeci83RcRrdaA==/oat/arm/base.vdex (pk.com.ke.peopleconnect.activities.K.a+116)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 001cc457  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2255586636+354)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 001d0d8f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+146)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 001e7b3f  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+762)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 003f688b  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+434)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00417814  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 001f3010  /data/app/pk.com.ke.peopleconnect-3XBY7V7mKYeci83RcRrdaA==/oat/arm/base.vdex (pk.com.ke.peopleconnect.activities.K.success+4)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 001cc457  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2255586636+354)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 001d0d8f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+146)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 001e7b3f  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+762)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 003f5001  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1024)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00413c94  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 001fcdd8  /data/app/pk.com.ke.peopleconnect-3XBY7V7mKYeci83RcRrdaA==/oat/arm/base.vdex (retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run+28)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 001cc457  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2255586636+354)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 001d0cdb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+82)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 003e7ccb  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+882)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 004252ff  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+30)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 00987251  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3fd000) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+64)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 009899a3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3fd000) (android.os.Looper.loop+1162)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 007e30bb  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3fd000) (android.app.ActivityThread.main+690)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.605 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 00420d75  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 003f988b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 000a181f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 00358161  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #29 pc 003595b3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+962)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #30 pc 003080f5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+40)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #31 pc 0011328f  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x10d000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+110)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #32 pc 00bdcc4b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3fd000) (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+114)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #33 pc 00be2445  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3fd000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+1916)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 00420d75  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #35 pc 003f988b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #36 pc 000a181f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #37 pc 00358161  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #38 pc 00357f75  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+300)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #39 pc 00299321  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+476)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 000712ff  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+38)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #41 pc 000737ab  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+478)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #42 pc 00002f15  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+728)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #43 pc 0008de5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #44 pc 00002bfd  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+40)
2020-01-28 16:16:09.606 5206-5206/? A/DEBUG:     #45 pc 00000306  <anonymous:f45d9000>
```

Following are default settings and dependencies used.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}

dependencies {

}
```

Comment: build.gradle or gradle.properties?

Comment: Added in the original post

Comment: I am part of the R8 team, and I have opened an issue in the R8 issue tracker, http://issuetracker.google.com/148521210. Would it be possible for you to follow up there? I have asked a few questions?

Comment: Replied on the thread.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved on the R8 bug tracker, [issue 148521210](https://issuetracker.google.com/148521210).